# How to detect current color of ellipse in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I am a beginner to wpf. I have an ellipse named ellipse1 and i fill it with white color. When i tap the ellipse it will change to red and if i again tap it it will again go back to white..
So i need to check the current color of the ellipse.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse1" 
         Fill="White" 
         Tap="Ellipse1_Tapped"></Ellipse>
```

So how can i detect the current color of ellipse.

```
if(....)
{
   Ellipse1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
else
{
   Ellipse1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public bool IsRed {get;set;}


void Ellipse1_Tapped(object sender, etcetera)
{
    Ellipse1.Fill = IsRed ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.White;
    IsRed = !IsRed;
}
```